# JSF - dataTable binding causing ERROR (can't convert)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm new in JSF. 
I need to retrieve `rowData` from `dataTable`.

Here is my code:

```
       <h:form>
            <h1><h:outputText value="List"/></h1>
            <p:dataTable value="#{accountBacking.dataModel}" 
                         binding="#{accountBacking.htmlTable}" 
                         var="item">
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Id"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Action"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{accountBacking.destination()}/>
                </p:column>
           </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

**Bean :**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;

@ManagedBean (name = "accountBacking")
@ViewScoped
public class AccountBacking implements Serializable {

private List<Account> daftarAccount;
private DataModel dataModel;
private HtmlDataTable htmlTable;
private AccountFacade service;
private Account account;

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{

}

public DataModel getDataModel() {
    dataModel = new ListDataModel();
    daftarAccount = service.findAll();
    if(daftarAccount != null && daftarAccount.size()>0)
        dataModel.setWrappedData(daftarAccount);

    return dataModel;
}

public void setDataModel(DataModel dataModel) {
    this.dataModel = dataModel;
}


public HtmlDataTable getHtmlTable() {
    return htmlTable;
}

public void setHtmlTable(HtmlDataTable htmlTable) {
    this.htmlTable = htmlTable;
}

public void destination(){
   acount = (Account)htmlTable.getRowData();
}
```

However, the binding tag inside `h:dataTable` cause an error, it says:

```
Cannot convert org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable@4f5b348a of type class org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable to class javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable
```

Why is that? And how to fix it so that I can retrieve `rowData` from the table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It happens because that is what you do in your code... How to fix it? Threat it as a org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable instead of javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable. How to retrieve a row or rowdata? Look at the PrimeFaces showcase... You seem to have found some very old tutorial or something

Answer (score 1):

This is happening 'cos **org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable** doesn't extend (IS NOT A) class **javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable**.

This is Primeface's Datable class hierarchy

Class DataTable

```
java.lang.Object
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent
        javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase
          javax.faces.component.UIData
              org.primefaces.component.api.UIData
                  org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable
```

Change

```
private HtmlDataTable htmlTable;
```

to

```
private DataTable htmlTable; // also change the import statement
```

and your code will work.